# assign values/string to cells using array vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign values to column z using an array but I am not getting desire results. I am testing to assign cell `Z1 = A`, cell `Z2 = B`, cell `Z3 = C`
Right now my codes assign all 3 cells to C.  I have posted my desire results below.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Long
Dim v As Variant

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws1
    v = Array("A", "B", "C")
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            For j = 1 To 3
                Cells(j, 26).Value = v(i)
            Next j
        Next i
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try this `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1").Resize(3,1).Value = v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Long
Dim v As Variant

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws1
    v = Array("A", "B", "C")
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
            For j = 1 To 3
                Cells(j, 26).Value = v(j - 1)
            Next j
        Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need to start with v(0)?

Comment: Its not compulsory. Its default situation in `VBA`. You can change it with `Option Base n`. Write this line of code above the module procedures. Then in each following array's LBound will set `n`.

Comment: Can you explain what the `i` loop is for?

Comment: That's not critic, not needed and not important! I tried to result code been compatible and same the original one. Who tries the original code, will find this matter easily, himself. I tried made less changes in the original code and because this matter not important and easy, I believe who writes the original question, will find this easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can set option base 1 so use valid row references when writing values out (if array lbound was 0 you wouldn't be able to use .Cells(0, 26) = v(0) as no row 0 in the sheet.

[Option Base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx): Used at module level to declare the default lower bound for array subscripts. Default is base 0.

Using Base 1 means can access all array elements and use same incremental variable for sheet and array i.e. can use just one long variable i.

```
Option Base 1
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i Long
Dim v As Variant

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

v = Array("A", "B", "C")

With ws1

        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                   .Cells(i, 26) = v(i)               
        Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW, you can make the code base-independent by using `.Cells(i + 1 - LBound(v), 26) = v(i)`

Comment: @YowE3K very true and a likely better solution.

Comment: If the OP isn't doing any other array-type stuff (or even if they are just used to base 1), using `Option Base 1` is by far the easiest solution.  But sometimes using Base 0 is needed and then tricks like subtracting the lower bound come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to read and write 1D or 2D VBA arrays into cells look at the code below:

```
Public Sub TestArrayReadAndWrite()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Set a 1D array in VBA
    ' Write the array to cells
    Dim v() As Variant
    v = Array("A", "B", "C")
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(3, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)
    ws.Range("A5").Resize(1, 3).Value = v

    ' Set a 3×3 array in VBA
    ' Write the array to cells
    Dim a() As Variant
    ReDim a(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
    a(1, 1) = "A11": a(1, 2) = "A12": a(1, 3) = "A13"
    a(2, 1) = "A21": a(2, 2) = "A22": a(2, 3) = "A13"
    a(3, 1) = "A31": a(3, 2) = "A32": a(3, 3) = "A13"

    ws.Range("C1").Resize(3, 3).Value = a

    ' Read Array 100×1 array of cells
    ' Modify the array by doubling the values
    ' Write the array back to the next column over
    Dim b() As Variant, i As Long
    b = ws.Range("G1").Resize(100, 1).Value
    For i = 1 To 100
        b(i, 1) = 2 * b(i, 1)
    Next i
    ws.Range("G1").Offset(0, 1).Resize(100, 1).Value = b
End Sub
```

And the result:

[image: RES]

It is a lot faster and concise to write entire arrays with one command by assigning to `Range().Resize(n,m).Value = x` then to loop through all the values and set them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple code.

```
Private Sub cmdFill_Click()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 26
        Cells(i, 26).Value = Chr(64 + i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can adjust 26 if you need only 3.